# Fill the image and img error box to desire height and width

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

```
  <>
      <div
        className={
          "border-2 border-amber-400 flex-shrink-0 w-[200px] h-[300px]"
        }
      >
        <img
          src={img}
          alt="Background Image"
          className="object-cover h-250 w-200"
        />
        Pictureeeee
      </div>
    </>
```

I want the  container always be constants to h-250 and w-200 for the layout.

[image]

Even if I set it to h-250 and w-200, it does not seem to work that way. I want the image to fill or stretch to cover all the spots if necessary. Also, that `?` box to be `h-250` and `w-200` as well.

Comment: May i know if you want the whole container containing picture and picture text to be of h-250 and w-200 or you want only the image to be of h-250 and w-200

Comment: Yeah, so I am trying to make the card design so that the main card size is h-300 and w-250. The picture covers 300 and 250. The rest is for the other contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a very small detail while using arbitary values, As there is no class named `h-250` and `w-200` you are not able to see the desired `height` and `width`

Change

```
className="object-cover h-250 w-200"
```

to

```
className="object-cover h-[250px] w-[200px]"
```